# Refer to one property from another?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

In Wicket, is it possible to have the value of one property reference another property?  For example, if I had a property like `<entry key="site.name">My Site</entry>`, is there any way for another property to use the value of `site.name` in its value?

I tried using something like `<entry key="page.title">About ${site.name}</entry>` but Wicket throws an exception because it's trying to resolve `site.name` as a property of the model... which makes sense.  But is there another syntax that *would* allow one property to refer to the value of another?

I'm running Wicket 6.6 by the way.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Wicket internationalization page? https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/everything-about-wicket-internationalization.html

Comment: Yes, I have. Do you have something more specific to point out? The closest example I see on the i18n page regards properties that will be applied to a Component with nested Components (which in turn might use their own properties.) What I don't see is an example of one property directly referencing another, which is what my question is asking. I assume it's not possible but Wicket sometimes surprises you with obscure, less-than-well-documented features. Am I just missing something on the page you referenced?

Comment: Have u tried using a properties file instead? I've never used Entry Keys personally but in this kind of situation I would use a properties file. Properties files allow you to reference other defined properties while creating a new property.

Comment: I tried just for the sake of it but it didn't work either.  XML and .properties are just two different formats that a java.util.Properties instance is able to parse to populate its key-value pairs.  But how those pairs were loaded doesn't affect whether it will do any sort of substitution after the fact.  It won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, a quick peak at the code shows that Wicket loads properties using [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), which simply parses a stream for key-value pairs.  It does not do any property expansion/substitution the way that developers might expect based on their experience with tools like ANT.

There are alternatives to `Properties`, like [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/), that perform expansion but `Properties` does not.  Therefore, neither does Wicket - it simply loads the properties as they are written.  The only substitution Wicket does is for **model properties** when a page is rendered, not for properties in the "properties file" sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
[StringResourceModel](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/working-with-wicket-models.html#WorkingwithWicketmodels-StringResourceModel) in Wicket.

Example in the doc:
`label.greetings=Welcome, ${name}!` and
`new Label("greetings", new StringResourceModel("label.greetings", this, new Model(user)));`

Comment: Yes, that allows substitution but it's off topic for the question.  You could use a StringResourceModel to resolve one property and substitute in the value of another.  However, that solution would require you to do that in Java and would not be suitable for cases where a property is referenced directly in markup, using the wicket:message element or attribute.  The question is about doing the substitution more statically, in the properties file itself.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I can think of solution only for a special case, like the mentioned wicket:message tag. In that case you can implement your own IComponentResolver, here is an example: http://pastebin.com/XazVtF1p

Comment: As you mentioned, that solution would only work for cases where you can use the new custom tag that's being handled. It wouldn't work for properties referenced anywhere else (e.g., wicket:message elements, wicket:message tags or StringResourceModels.)  But I must say that is a slick solution for what it is.  :)  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can write your own ResourceModel that replaces the keys: http://pastebin.com/38WB2XDF</strike>

The ReplacingResourceModel will be available / is available in:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-minis</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0-M6</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-minis</artifactId>
    <version>6.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```